# Django not detecting foreign key in a ManyToManyField when passed through a Model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a relation between the Subject model and the Teacher model and the Classes model. This is how I am relating it-

> A subject can be taught in many classes and a class can have many subjects. A subject in a class can be taught by only one teacher.

So basically what I am trying to do is this- there's a subject, say Maths, the subject can be taught in many classes, say Class 1 to Class 10 and there will be various teachers teaching in different classes.

Here's my Subject model:

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Classes, through='ThroughTeacher')
```

ThroughTeacher model:

```
class ThroughTeacher(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Classes, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Classes model:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    class_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
```

Teacher model:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
subjects.ThroughTeacher: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 
'subjects.Subjects.classes', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Subjects' or 'Classes'.
```

Comment: Since you use it as a `through=...` model from `Subjects` to `Classes`, you need to add at least a `ForeignKey` to `Subjects`, and a `ForeignKey` to `Classes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use it as a `through=...` model from `Subjects` to `Classes`, you need to add at least a `ForeignKey` to `Subjects`, and a `ForeignKey` to `Classes`.

You thus model the `ThroughTeacherModel` as:

```
class ThroughTeacher(models.Model):
    class_ = models.ForeignKey(Classes, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```